# how to solve liner equations with decimal values like 2n=0.58(12 - n)

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve problems given in the book "Algebra - A Complete Introduction". The author in chapter Liner Algebra has given some examples how to solve a liner equation which I understood well. I was solving all the problem given in the exercise until this equation

```
2n = 0.58(12 - n)
```

I have solved it like below

```
Diving both sides by 2 gives   
n = 0.29(12-n)
n = 3.48 - 0.29n = 3.19
```

This was no different from other exercise problems except having to multiply the odd decimal numbers which I have used calculator for time saving.

I also thought of doing it like this to avoid decimal value

```
n = 0.29(12-n)
```

Multiply by 100 to remove decimal

100n = 29(12 - n)

But I am not sure from here if this can be simplified to avoid the odd number multiplications. Can this be simplified?

Comment: $29(12-n)=30(12-n)-(12-n)$, is one of the tricks to avoid 29

Comment: Dividing by $2$ was not a good idea, but it is not incorrect. From $n=0.29(12-n)$ you reached $n=3.48-0.29n$. Then there is a mistake. You should next get $1.29n=3.48$, and then $n=\frac{3.48}{1.29}$.